# .htaccess file Mod_rewrite - remove extension and remove trailing slash

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Hey i'm having problems with my .htaccess file and with removing a trailing slash at the end of a file.
I read that it is best to have a the URI structure as having 
`http://www.example.com/folder/file`

rather than having:
`http://www.example.com/folder/file/`
 becuase apparently a trailing slash renders it at the directory level.

So i'm almost there, got this from another source on stackoverflow but it adds a slash to a document, rather than take it away... and i can't seem to work out how to take it away and redirect anything with a slash that isn't a directory, and please forgive me, as i don't know much about .htaccess files.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php 

# Forces a trailing slash to be added
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1
```

Comment: thanks, but unfortunately i get a 404 error if i take the trailing slash off.. and i don't want the trailing slash on a document

Comment: is your .htaccess in the root folder of your website?